# Fourier transform of an an (almost) periodic function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions, almost-periodic-functions

I am not sure about the terminology here but I have a function for which I know is almost periodic in the sense that for integer values of $k$ we have

$$f(x+k)=e^{-|k|}f(x)$$

Is there any way to find the Fourier transform of such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only function verifying this is the function $0$. If you take the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ on both sides you find indeed
$$
e^{2i\pi kx}\,\widehat{f(x)} = e^{-|k|}\,\widehat{f(x)}
$$
and so taking absolute values
$$
|\widehat{f(x)}| = e^{-|k|}\,|\widehat{f(x)}|
$$
and the only solution when $k\neq 0$ is $f=0$.

---

Notice that it can be proved without using the Fourier transform by considering your equation with $k=1$ at the point $x$ and $k=-1$ at the point $x+1$, leading to
$f(x) = e^{-1} \, f(x+1)$ and $f(x+1) = e^{-1} \, f(x)$. Thus
$$
f(x) = e^{-2} \, f(x)
$$
or equivalently, $f=0$.